# Paper Review about weekly supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, transfer-learning

The authors have mentioned that the major challenge of the problem is that "large dataset of CT-scan images are not publicly available due to privacy concerns and obtaining very accurate model becomes difficult". As the author proposed the transfer learning based method, the authors should also consider the alternative methods, e.g., weakly supervised methods, methods with conventional texture analysis and coupling of fully convolutional networks and shallow networks:

Hu, Shaoping, et al. "Weakly supervised deep learning for covid-19 infection detection and classification from CT images." IEEE Access 8 (2020): 118869-118883.

Soltaninejad, Mohammadreza, et al. "Supervised learning based multimodal MRI brain tumour segmentation using texture features from supervoxels." Computer methods and programs in biomedicine 157 (2018): 69-84.

Zhang, Lei, Guang Yang, and Xujiong Ye. "Automatic skin lesion segmentation by coupling deep fully convolutional networks and shallow network with textons." Journal of Medical Imaging 6.2 (2019): 024001.

I am not able to understand anything like how I will do please help